# Cant use compiled C file in Flutter using dart:ffi

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to use C code and call main method in flutter.i'm not sure if we can do this in flutter yet...

I compiled C file and it's Ok.
when i use it in dart file and run it with command

`dart myDartCode.dart` **it works**.

but in flutter i get this :

[image]

this is my class :

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;

typedef HelloWorld = void Function();
typedef hello_world_func = ffi.Void Function();

class TestFFI {
  TestFFI() {
    final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(
      '/Users/vahab/Documents/Develop/vscode_test/flutter_vscode1/
      lib/funcs.dylib');

  final HelloWorld hello = dylib
    .lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<hello_world_func>>('hello_world')
    .asFunction();

  hello();

  print("DONE!");
 }
}
```

**Is it possible to do that in flutter yet??**

Comment: https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-5-super-charged-development-328822024970

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/88a7d8acbc02c314b65a7d938de633085810b18e

Comment: Thanks but i already said that it's ok  with dart compiler and a sample..i cant make it in flutter..

Comment: Could it be the path you are using? Try putting the dylib in the app assets and then copy it to the device. Use the new path in the device after that.

Comment: Refer to this to how to copy from assets https://stackoverflow.com/a/53292569/5617722

Comment: The error message is stating that your native library is not compiled for simulator (i.e. x86_64). Could you try to run the same exact code in a real device? It should work.

Comment: thanks.i will try to do that

Comment: path is ok and i'm trying to create correct so file.thanks guys